# How to correct this awk code without eval?

Tags: shell, awk

The following piece of **awk** code works fine if I use **eval** builtin

```
var='$1,$2'
ps | eval "awk '{print $var}'"
```

But when I try to knock off **eval** and use awk variable as substitute then I am not getting the expected result

```
ps | awk -v v1=$var '{print v1}'   # output is $1,$2
ps | awk -v v1=`echo $var` '{print v1}'  # output is same as above
ps | awk -v v1=$var '{print $v1}'  # output is all the fields of ps command
ps | eval "awk -v v1=$var '{print v1}'"  # output is column of comma
```

How to get the desire output without using **eval**?

Comment: Since your 'var' is assigned with values of another two variables, its required to decipher with eval. Does using 

awk -v v1=`eval echo $var` '{print v1}'

helps?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double-quotes in the `awk` command:

```
ps | awk "{print $var}"
```

Comment: Simple as that :)  Sometime its hard to see the forest for the trees.

Comment: @Jotne Yes.  That said, attempting to expand variables in single quotes seems to bite everyone so often.

Comment: @Jotne Moreover, using double-quotes while assigning in this case, i.e. saying `var="$1,$2"` won't (obviously) work.

Comment: @devnull I don't see $var getting expanded to correct variables value of '$1,$2' if we surround with double quotes?.

Comment: @user1587504 Did you see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042590/how-to-correct-this-awk-code-without-eval/20042720?noredirect=1#comment29850027_20042720)?

Comment: @devnull With awk "{print $var}" , it is not expanding to required value of $var, which is applied as filter of 'ps' command.
My example :

 x=unix;y=test;var='$x,$y'
 
 awk "{print $var}" -- does nothing
 
 however awk -v v1=`eval echo $var` '{print v1}' does.

Comment: @user1587504 Your comment makes the question entirely different.  Please, __please__, include such information in your question and not comments when you receive answers.

Comment: @devnull awesome!! if I have to use awk variable here then how do I do it?